# How to fill in the joint gap in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

Lets say I have a spring joint in SpriteKit,

when I pull one sprite node from another there is empty space inbetween

How would I fill this space up with the same colour as the sprite nodes

When I let go of the sprite node it bounces back into place

I will also need the extra colour to erase when the spring moves back.

How can I do this in SpriteKit

Comment: So when you pull it, it gets pulled from it's original location?

Comment: Yea but I will also add more spring joints to make a sort of elastic band.

Comment: @Jackster Is there any relevant code you could paste here? Or is this just a general question?

Comment: More of a general question on how to fill in space between two nodes . I am trying to make a sort of elastic band effect.